# Sorting Two Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create a simple program that will compare an associative array based on another associative array:

```
$ArrayPriority = array("P1"=>3, "P2"=>5, "P3"=>1, "P4"=>1, "P5"=>4);
$ArrayBurst = array("P1"=>1, "P2"=>2, "P3"=>5, "P4"=>6, "P5"=>9);
```

Is there a sort function to produce the output for `$ArrayBurst`:

```
P3 = 5
P4 = 6
P1 = 1
P5 = 9
P2 = 2
```

Basically, I want to sort `$ArrayBurst` based on `$ArrayPriority` then display the `$ArrayBurst`'s keys and values.

For now, I can only sort the `$ArrayPriority` based of the values and I used `array_multisort` to do so:

```
array_multisort(array_values($ArrayPriority), SORT_ASC, array_keys($ArrayPriority), SORT_ASC, $ArrayPriority);
```

which arranges `$ArrayPriority` to:

```
P3 = 1
P4 = 1
P1 = 3
P5 = 4
P2 = 5
```

Comment: Where are you coming up with that output. What is the formula?

Comment: Does it have to be a stable sort? Or is [6, 5, 1, 9, 2] also acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do they need to have the same order established in `$ArrayPriority` if they have the same value in `$ArrayPriority`? If not, this should work.

```
<?php

$ArrayPriority = array("P1"=>3, "P2"=>5, "P3"=>1, "P4"=>1, "P5"=>4);
$ArrayBurst = array("P1"=>1, "P2"=>2, "P3"=>5, "P4"=>6, "P5"=>9);

asort($ArrayPriority);
$output = [];
foreach($ArrayPriority as $key => $value) {
    echo "<p>" . $key . " = " . $ArrayBurst[$key] . "</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?
  $ArrayPriority = array("P1"=>3, "P2"=>5, "P3"=>1, "P4"=>1, "P5"=>4);
  $ArrayBurst = array("P1"=>1, "P2"=>2, "P3"=>5, "P4"=>6, "P5"=>9);

  uasort($ArrayPriority, function ($p, $n) { return $p - $n;});
  uksort($ArrayBurst, function ($p, $n) use($ArrayPriority) {
    return $ArrayPriority[$p] - $ArrayPriority[$n];
  });

  echo '<pre>' . print_r(array($ArrayPriority, $ArrayBurst), 1) . '</pre>';
```

And [online pad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JkQ7hn)

P.S. U may change the code to preserve bursts' order with the same priority, i.e to handle P3 earlier than P4 according to order of `$ArrayPriority`'s keys .